# Ruby on Rails 7 with esbuild generate multiples files .js

Tags: javascript, build, production, ruby-on-rails-7, esbuild

Ruby on rails 7 with esbuild
rails new app-rails7 -j esbuild -d postgresql

generate on package.json

```
# package.json
"build": "esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --sourcemap --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=assets"

# Procfile.dev
web: unset PORT && bin/rails server
js: yarn build --watch
```

generate build file in app/assets/builds/application.js

render in layout app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload", defer: true %>
```

More when I need to separate into more than two load js files how to solve?

what i want to do

```
app/assets/builds/application.js
app/assets/builds/admin_load.js
```

After researching a lot and doing several tests to arrive at what I wanted to get to something that worked for my case.

```
# package.json
         
"scripts": { 
   "build": "esbuild app/javascript/application.js --bundle --minify --analyze=verbose --sourcemap --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=assets", 
   "build_admin": "esbuild app/javascript/admin_load.js --bundle --minify --analyze=verbose --sourcemap --outfile=app/assets/builds --public-path=assets"
 }
```

under development in Procfile.dev add the line

```
js_admin: yarn build_admin --watch
```

otherwise can like this

```
# package.json
"scripts": {
    "build": "esbuild app/javascript/application.js app/javascript/admin_load.js --bundle --minify --analyze=verbose --sourcemap --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=assets"
}
```

this way we can call both js files load in different templates

```
# app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload", defer: true %>

# app/views/layouts/admin.html.erb
<%= javascript_include_tag "admin_load", "data-turbo-track": "reload", defer: true %>
```

We can still do a rake task to add the new admin_load.js build inside the task
rails assets:precompile

```
# lib/tasks/my_task.rake
namespace :javascript do
  desc "Build your JavaScript bundle"
  task :build do
    system "yarn install && yarn run build_admin"
  end
end

Rake::Task["assets:precompile"].enhance(["javascript:build"])
```